# Having trouble configuring ssl for django apache2

Tags: django, apache

when i run 'https://example.com' i see 'Apache2 Default Page'

how can i fix this error, this is my config ssl

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key 
</VirtualHost>
```